Tailscale docker reverse proxy to port 443
I am trying to run vaultwarden which does on Port 80, without tailscale json config file, but not 443 which is refused according the logs.
2024/04/01 14:38:07 http: proxy error: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused

If I create and use a json file according here https://tailscale.com/blog/docker-tailscale-guide than tailscaled wont connect tailscale servers.
So for test reasons I dont use config file and exec to tailscale docker container.
According to this commands https://tailscale.com/kb/1242/tailscale-serve it should open port 443 to serve
tailscale serve https://localhost:443
tailscale serve --bg --https=443 127.0.0.1:443

Both of them ends up with 502 Error.
Tested tailscale serve --bg --tcp 443 tcp://127.0.0.1:443 which allowed a SSL connection but without content.
Thats my docker file:
services:

  vaultwarden:
    image: vaultwarden/server:latest
    depends_on:
      - vaultwarden-tailscale
    container_name: vaultwarden
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
     - vw-data:/data:rw
    environment:
     #- ADMIN_TOKEN=${ADMIN_TOKEN}
     - WEBSOCKET_ENABLED=true
     - DOMAIN=${DOMAIN}
    network_mode: service:vaultwarden-tailscale


  vaultwarden-tailscale:
    image: tailscale/tailscale:latest
    container_name: vaultwarden-tailscale
    hostname: vaultwarden
    environment:
      - TS_AUTHKEY=tskey-auth-KEYFILE
      - TS_STATE_DIR=/var/lib/tailscale
      #- TS_SERVE_CONFIG=/config/vaultwarden.json
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/vaultwarden-tailscale/state:/var/lib/tailscale
      - ${PWD}/vaultwarden-tailscale/config:/config
      - /dev/net/tun:/dev/net/tun
    cap_add:
      - net_admin
      - sys_module
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - vaultwarden-net


volumes:
  vw-data:
    driver: local
  vaultwarden-tailscale:
    driver: local

networks:
  vaultwarden-net:
    external: true

Would be about any suggestion, help. Thank you

If you don't have a TLS listener running for the vaultwarden/server, you probably want the first answer listed below. If you're definitely running a TLS listener on vaultwarden/server, see the second two answers below. The gist is that you need to proxy the vaulwarden/server backend on an HTTP port or proxy the vaultwarden/server backend on an HTTPS port that tailscale isn't already going to use and make sure the proxy trusts the TLS certificate vaultwarden/server is going to present.
Proxy TLS termination and plaintext backend
From the Dockerfile it seems like it exposes 80 and listens on 80. If that's the case, you would want the tailscale reverse proxy upstream to be just localhost:80 like so:
tailscale serve localhost:80
This would start a TLS listener on port 443 (default) bound to the tunnel interface. Tailscale serve would automatically obtain a TLS certificate (if you have MagicDNS enabled) for you and the terminate TLS before sending traffic to the backend over plaintext HTTP.
Proxy TLS termination and TLS backend
If vaultwarden/server actually does have a TLS listener running, it would need to be on a different port than what tailscale serve is going to use. tailscale serve uses 443 by default, which is probably what you want, but the backend would need to use a different port because the two containers share the same network namespace. You could use 8443 if you want. An important caveat here is that you need a valid TLS certificate for vaultwarden/server to use otherwise the tailscale reverse proxy won't trust it! The following command would run a tailscale TLS listener on port 443 and proxy the backend over HTTPS:
tailscale serve https://localhost:8443
This will not work correctly with a self-signed certificate, though. Read on for more details.
Backend TLS certificate validity
If you're using a self-signed or otherwise untrusted/invalid certificate for vaultwarden/servers TLS listener, tailscale will not establish a connection with it unless you've made modifications to the host's trust store. It would be entirely up to you to configure trusted CA certificates and use your own PKI. However, like many other tools, tailscale serve allows you to communicate with the backend using TLS and skip certificate verification via a pseudo-protocol https+insecure:// in your backend address. To run a tailscale listener on port 443, proxying a backend TLS port 8443 with certificate verification turned off, use the following command:
tailscale serve https+insecure://localhost:8443
